# Batch file. Delete all the files from subfolders that are named as admin

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I am working on a script in Batch that first find all the subfolders in a directory that are named as **admin**. The script first look at all the folders in a directory and if it finds a folder named as admin it deletes all the files from that sub folder but also from child subfolders except a file named as **fn.asp**.

So far the script is finding all the subfolders that are named as admin. The issue I am unable to solve is that when we find the subfolder named as admin, we get its path and a for loops go through all the subfolders in that path and delete all the files except the one mentioned above. The only issue I am having is I'm unable to pass the path in the following code.

```
FOR /R [path] %%variable IN ( set_of_file_filters ) DO (
   command
)
```

This is the code I have written.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set dirPath=D:\batchs

cd /d %dirPath%

:: Find all the sub-folders and further child folders that are named as admin.
for /d /r %%a in (*) do (
if %%~nxa == admin (
echo folder name admin was found...
echo "%%a"

for /R "%%a" %%f in (*) do (
    set fileName=%%~nxf
    echo %%f
    if "!fileName!"=="fn.asp" (
        echo FOUND: !fileName!
    ) else (
         echo OTHER: !fileName!
         ::del "%%a"
         echo File: !fileName! deleted
    )
)

echo.
) else (
echo Folder named admin was not found
)
)
```

It would be really helpful if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong as I am unable to find out the issue.

Comment: Do not use the double colon as a comment inside a parenthesised code block. Shouldn't you be using %%f for the delete?

Comment: @Squashman I commented it out because I wanted to test the upper for loop and yes it would be %%f instead of %%a. The issue lies in this line for /R "%%a" %%f in (*) do. where %%a is the path of the sub folder that is named as admin.

Comment: Squashman is saying that `::` inside of loops breaks things and that you should use `REM` instead.